# Not able to add a space after input field

Tags: javascript

I append an `input` field into a `div`. What I want is a single space after the input field.

This is what I have tried:

```js
const el = document.createElement('input');
el.setAttribute('type', 'number');
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
/*
  Also tried it with:
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0'));
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('&nbsp;'));
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + ' ';
*/

const id = document.getElementById('content');
id.appendChild(el);
id.focus();
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'single space' after the input field? You mean the space in the input, or the spacing around it? You should be just adding some styling if you want to style the actual container itself.

Comment: Yes, the space should be outside of the `<input>` tag. Is there a way to do it without CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

```js
const id = document.getElementById('content');
const input = document.createElement('input');
const space = document.createTextNode('\u00A0')
input.setAttribute('type', 'number');


id.append(input, space);
id.focus();
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true"></div>
```